# Trying to get a jFrame to pop up do some stuff and then close out when the timer expires

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HoorayWithTimer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int counter;

public HoorayWithTimer() {
    initComponents();
}
/*
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    timerLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(timerLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 334, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 271, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(timerLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    timerLabel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("timerLabel");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HoorayWithTimer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HoorayWithTimer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HoorayWithTimer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HoorayWithTimer.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


    Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            HoorayWithTimer.setVisible(false);
            HoorayWithTimer.dispose();

        }
    });

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new HoorayWithTimer().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel timerLabel;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

So yeah i have a menu from the menu you can launch 3 different games when somone wins I want to pop up a jFrame that says hooray you win with music etc.
then after 10 seconds of the hooray screen. Close the hooray screen and go back to the still open game. The menu always stays open open in the background because i couldnt get it to close or dispose() either.

Always get an error :
Non-Static method setVisible(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context

I am kinda new to java so bear with me....lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is next:

1) You try to call non-static methods of `JFrame` from static context(your `main` method) here:

```
HoorayWithTimer.setVisible(false);
HoorayWithTimer.dispose();
```

2) Read [java basics about variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

3) You can write your `Timer` like next:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            HoorayWithTimer.this.setVisible(false);
            HoorayWithTimer.this.dispose();
        }
    });
    timer.start();
```

and use it in constructor, in method `initComponents`. Just delete your `Timer` initialization in `main` method, and put above code after `pack()` method in `initComponents`. In this case your frame will be closed after 10 seconds. I think it helps you.

Comment: ok so I couldnt easily place that code above pack() since it was generated code by netbeans from the GUI builder.

Comment: I figured out a way and it still doesnt close the window after 10 seconds, but it did get rid of the errors that i had in the code.

Comment: You are welcome. I recommend to use clear swing code instead of some builders.

Comment: yeah but the builders make it easy at first.... but then real difficult later...lol